# Spring @RequestParam Map<String, String> does not work in POST method

Tags: spring-mvc, http-post

from the Spring documentation I took the following:

> **public @interface RequestParam**
>
> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request parameter. Supported for annotated handler methods in Servlet and Portlet environments.
>
> ...
>
> If the method parameter is Map or MultiValueMap and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.

Now I have created a controller for test purposes. It has a GET and a POST method and each uses a *@RequestParam java.util.Map* as only parameter. In the method body I am only trying to print the size of the map. When I send requests (GET/POST) only in the GET method the map contains any key/value pairs. I am using the Poster add-on in Firefox and I am sending **three** parameters.

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="test/method", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String testmethodGet(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {

        System.out.println("GET: " + params.size()); // prints GET: 3   
        return "";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="test/method", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String testmethodPost(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {

        System.out.println("POST: " + params.size()); // prints POST: 0
        return "";

    }

}
```

Would any of you guys know why @RequestParam Map would not work with a POST request or whether I need to change something to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, it works on GET and POST method. It was solely my fault. The initially given code will work, when you actually pass parameters to the POST request.

Consider the following JS ( jQuery ) code as how to send a valid request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test/method",
    data: { param1: param1, param2: param2, param3: param3 },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("testPost successful!");
    },    
    dataType: "html", // expected return value type
    error: function(data, status, error) {
        console.log("testPost with errors!");
    }
});
```

Comment: do you know how to send from postman instead of ajax for testing purpose ?

Comment: @ArunGowdru, since this is JSON is should be pretty straight forward. Endpoint would be http://yourhost/api/test/method and the request body would be { "param1": "value", "param2": "value" }.

Answer (score 2):

Spring does not know how to convert a `String` received as a `request param` to a map.

> String-based values extracted from the request including request
>   parameters, path variables, request headers, and cookie values may
>   need to be converted to the target type of the method parameter or
>   field (e.g., binding a request parameter to a field in an
>   @ModelAttribute parameter) they're bound to. If the target type is not
>   String, Spring automatically converts to the appropriate type. All
>   simple types such as int, long, Date, etc. are supported. You can
>   further customize the conversion process through a WebDataBinder (see
>   the section called “Customizing WebDataBinder initialization”) or by
>   registering Formatters with the FormattingConversionService (see
>   Section 7.6, “Spring 3 Field Formatting”).

Spring does provide support for maps via the `HttpServletReqeust` which could be used to obtain the map via `getParameterMap()`.

```
   @RequestMapping(value="test/method", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String testmethodPost(HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println("POST: " + request.getParameterMap().size()); // prints POST: 0
        return "";

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. Just to make sure. I am using the map, because I want to get a map of String key/value pairs. I am not expecting one of the parameters to be a map. And MultiValueMap is only a map as well ie Map<K,List<V>>.