# Why can't we map request parameters as a Map parameter in method?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to pass input param as Map.

```
@RequestParam(value = "map") Map<String, String> map
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the HTTP Method you're using? As it really depends on that. If you're using POST, check this [Spring @RequestParam Map<String, String> does not work in POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809098/spring-requestparam-mapstring-string-does-not-work-in-post-method)

Comment: I am using GET method.

Answer (score 0):

We should not use @RequestParam(value = "map") for Map params. If we are passing map as a parameter Map, it will generate all the request parameter as a key, value. So we cannot declare the value. If we declare the value like @RequestParam(value = "map"). we will end up with below issue .

"message" : "Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Map]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Map]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found",

I would suggest to use.
@RequestParam Map map
or 
@RequestParam MultiValueMap map

This works fine.